# Iteration over object Properties using Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List` of `Publication` objects and I want to get the the corresponding `PublicationKeyword` for each of `Publication` to the map in the form of: `Map<Integer, Map<Keyword, Integer>>`, where the key for outer map is the id of `Publication` from the list and the value is a map, where the key is a `keyword` object and `integer` is it's frequency.

Currently, I am doing it this way:

```
public Map<Integer, Map<Keyword, Integer>> getFrequencies(List<Publication> publications) {
        Map<Integer, Map<Keyword, Integer>> resultSet = new HashMap<>();
        for (Publication publication : publications) {
            Map<Keyword, Integer> frequencyMappings = new HashMap<>();
            for (PublicationKeyword pubKeyword : publication.getPublicationKeyword()) {
                frequencyMappings.put(pubKeyword.getKeyword(), pubKeyword.getConceptFrequency());
            }
            resultSet.put(publication.getIdPaper(), frequencyMappings);
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
```

But, the thing is that I want to use Java 8 streams to achieve this. Is it possible to be done? And if yes, what is the proper way to do this? The things which are confusing me: the nested for-loops and declaration of variable inside for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
return publications.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Publication::getIdPaper,
        publication -> publication.getPublicationKeyword()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                PublicationKeyword::getKeyword,
                PublicationKeyword::getConceptFrequency))));
```

Comment: looks great. Short question, which is more efficient: using streams or classic Java 7 way?

Comment: Define "efficient".

Comment: @Cap As a general rule, streams will be less efficient than a simple loop, but you should usually focus on readability and only optimize when there's a demonstrable need. The exception to the above is with parallel streams, which *may* be more efficient than a sequential operation. But again, never assume.

Comment: @shmosel oh, than I was clearly thinking wrong. I thought simple `stream` is also assuming parallelism (so that it's distributed over multi-cores), but now I realize that I need parallel streams instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, "efficient" in terms of multi-core (multiple CPU) usage simultaneously.

Comment: @Cap Unless there's some heavy lifting in those getters, I would say this is a poor candidate for parallelization.

Comment: @shmosel nope, shouldn't be that heavy. Just there are around mio. of `PublicationKeyword` objects.

Comment: @shmosel how can I do something like:  `PublicationKeyword::getKeyword::getName`? So to say in order to get the property of the property?

Comment: @Cap Use a regular lambda: `publicationKeyword -> publicationKeyword.getKeyword().getName()`

Comment: Also, I am getting `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Integer,Object> to Map<Integer,Map<Keyword,Integer>>`

Comment: @Cap [Compiles for me.](http://ideone.com/ZX6SKB) You must have changed something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151008/discussion-between-cap-and-shmosel).

Comment: @cap parallel streams utilize cores better